# Memcached returns null even though cache was hit

Tags: java, memcached

We are using following Memcached whalin client library. The Memcached jar is placed in tomcat/lib folder. When we start our web application the 
it returns null even though cache was hit ( found it through -v flag). 
The cache is getting set as we can see the cache objects when we telnet the host on which we have hosted the memcache service using the get method.
It works fine when we use deprecated constructor that takes classloader argument or when we move Memcache jar in WEB-INF/lib from tomcat/lib
Could you please help us pinpoint the issue

Comment: Need code please.

Comment: To paraphrase, you're saying "it doesn't work". There isn't much detail to go on for others here to provide solutions. General stuff applies: verify any assumptions you've made, use a debugger to step through the code, add debugging statements.

Comment: Initially we used to package the memcached-client jar inside our application war. 
But we changed the packaging of the design as one more application war was added and the memcached-client jar was common to both. So, we removed the jar from the war packaging and placed in the /tomcat/lib folder. 
After adding the jar in /tomcat/lib folder then the placed loggers while setting the cache and also during the getting the cache. 
We can see that cache is getting set but when we get cache it shows null.
We also used telnet to see whether we can the see the cache which has been set. It was there